# What happens when we subtract a char integer from another char integer?

Tags: java, recursion

The following code is a way to convert String into an Integer using recursion. I understood the process but cannot figure out what is happening when we do this:

`str.charAt(0) - '0'`

We can easily convert it into an int or double using parseInt or parseDouble. Then why are we subtracting a char '0' from a String (which is a number)? How does this convert our character into an int or double?

```
// Java implementation of the approach to convert a String to an Integer using Recursion
public class GFG { 

    // Recursive function to convert string to integer 
    static int stringToInt(String str) 
    { 

        // If the number represented as a string 
        // contains only a single digit 
        // then returns its value 
        if (str.length() == 1) 
            return (str.charAt(0) - '0'); 

        // Recursive call for the sub-string 
        // starting at the second character 
        double y = stringToInt(str.substring(1)); 

        // First digit of the number 
        double x = str.charAt(0) - '0'; 

        // First digit multiplied by the 
        // appropriate power of 10 and then 
        // add the recursive result 
        // For example, xy = ((x * 10) + y) 
        x = x * Math.pow(10, str.length() - 1) + y; 
        return (int)(x); 
    } 

    // Driver code 
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    { 
        String str = "1235"; 
        System.out.print(stringToInt(str)); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Look at this: `'5' - '0'` ... it equals 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ASCII for '0' is 48 and '1' is 49 till '9' is 57, So by subtracting the digit character from '0' you will get the number in decimal [ASCII_Table](https://www.asciitable.com/)